# making react native to use a Android simulator located at other computer

Tags: android, reactjs, docker, react-native

Is there a way to configure

```
npx react-native run-android
```

to use a virtual Android device in another computer? I need this because for a given project I can run

```
npm start
npx react-native
```

from a docker container but I need to use an android simulator located inside the host but outside the container.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to connect a device with adb over the network

[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless

So yes you could in theory have an emulator on the host and connect to its ip from your VM.

Set the target in your VM:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Connect to its IP:

```
adb connect device_ip_address
```